# Should the app be downloaded from Playstore to track installs? or is there any other way to do the installation tracking test

Tags: android, branch.io

I am integrated and configured branch.io SDK according to docs.branch.io and create a link from branch.io dashboard to track installs but I am only able to see click counter and app re-open counter but not showing installs counter.
   Manifest.xml

```
<meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey" android:value="my_live_key" />
    <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.BranchKey.test" android:value="my_test_key" />

    <!-- Branch testing (TestMode "true" to simulate fresh installs on dev environment) -->
    <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.TestMode" android:value="false" />


    <!-- Branch install referrer tracking -->
    <receiver android:name="io.branch.referral.InstallListener" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.vending.INSTALL_REFERRER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name=".activities.MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar.Splash"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize|stateHidden">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>


        <!-- Branch URI scheme -->
        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="goalwise" android:host="open" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>


        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="xjgf5.app.link" />
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="xjgf5-alternate.app.link" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Application class

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    // Initialize the Branch object

    Branch.getAutoInstance(this);
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    Branch.getInstance().initSession(new Branch.BranchReferralInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInitFinished(JSONObject referringParams, BranchError error) {
            if (error == null) {
                Log.i("BRANCH SDK", referringParams.toString());
                // Retrieve deeplink keys from 'referringParams' and evaluate the values to determine where to route the user
                // Check '+clicked_branch_link' before deciding whether to use your Branch routing logic
            } else {
                Log.i("BRANCH SDK", error.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }, this.getIntent().getData(), this);

    IntegrationValidator.validate(MainActivity.this);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please change the following line in your manifest file from:

```
  <meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.TestMode" android:value="false" />
```

TO

```
<meta-data android:name="io.branch.sdk.TestMode" android:value="true" />
```

This would simulate an install even if the install was not made from the Play store and Branch would report that on the dashboard. This is called as test mode. More information [here](https://docs.branch.io/apps/android/#simulate-an-install).

Comment: thanks, AniV I am facing one more problem. In the device, the app is already installed but when I am clicking on deep-link it redirects to me browser instead of an app. You can refer mention video link which can help to understand the problem     https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzP0jJeEWxXOOVVVdkpDSElBc1dYZ0h3a0JWTl9HQm5BdWc4/view?usp=sharing